# Taking a Shower after the Mikvah

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath, water, cleaning, showering-bathing

Is there any problem with taking a shower after dipping in the Mikvah? I once heard there was.

Comment: A man or woman?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The source for this is [Shabbos 14a](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14314&st=&pgnum=28&hilite=) and [Yorah Deah 201:75 Rama](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9732&st=&pgnum=289).

http://www.dailyhalacha.com/displayRead.asp?readID=1814

> As in many Halachos there is a
>   Machlokes. In summary according to the
>   custom of the Ashkenazim, a woman
>   should not bathe or shower after
>   immersing in the Mikveh. Sepharadim,
>   however, do not follow this custom,
>   and thus Sephardic women may bathe or
>   shower immediately after immersion
>   without any concern.

Comment: Does the same apply to men?

Comment: Hm. The reason given for the preference (not prohibition) for not showering immediately afterwards is that people may think it's the shower, not the mikva, that did the purification. This would be funny with regards to men, as for a men's mikva the concept is *tevilat Ezra*, which actually can be fulfilled by a shower! My guess is there's no need to add what's only a preference for Ashkenazic women, on top of the meritorious-but-unrequired practice of men using the mikva, especially as the reason doesn't apply.

Comment: @Shalom - It is not a universal consensus that a[n unqualified] shower suffices for men either.

Comment: It is definately a problem by ladies. By men it is not such an issue as you mentioned.

Comment: @WAF see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2966/mikvah-in-shower

Comment: R' Shmuel Wosner ([*Shevet HaLevi*](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1415&pgnum=123) 5:125) holds that a woman may shower once she gets home from the mikva, and it's my understanding that that is the prevalent custom among Ashkenazim.

Answer (score 8):

There is a story of a great Rav (no official source) who would shower after the mikvah. When asked about his custom he answered:

> **Before going into the mikvah I shower
>   because of the mitzvah "ואהבת לרעך".
>   When coming out I shower because of
>   "כמוך".**

Comment: Shouldn't that be the other way around? I.e. the mikva is for one's personal purity, while the shower is for one's fellows' olfactory comfort.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I assume this means that the shower before was so he wouldn't dirty the _mikve_, and after in case others had.

Comment: @msh210. Oh, right. I misread the comment a bit.

Comment: I heard the quote as: "I take a shower before because of V'ahavta Lre'acha K'mocha. I take a shower after because some people aren't makpid on V'ahavta Lre'acha K'mocha." It's supposedly attributed to R' Shlomo Zalman Auerbach [over here](http://www.hashkafah.com/index.php?/topic/48431-shower-after-mikvah/page__view__findpost__p__1025151)

Comment: @yydl I've heard both versions and prefer the first (from a humor point of view). Thanks for the link, but "they say" isn't really a source, which is why I didn't feel comfortable mentioning Rav Auerbach _zt"l's_ name.

Comment: I heard a 3rd version: There are 3 parts to the Mitzvah going to the Mikva. The shower before is a mitzvah bein adam lechavero, the mikva itself is a mitzva bein adam Lamakom, and the shower after the mikvah is a mitzva bein-adam-le'atzmo!

Comment: R Shlomo Aviner (On the air, p. 117) quotes the story as @yydl has it in the name of RSZA

Answer (score 1):

R [Shlomo Aviner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Aviner) answers this question in his book [On the air](https://www.ateret.org.il/uploads/files/radio%20-%20ch%201-277.pdf) p. 117.

He writes **there was an issue at one point** because *mikvaot* were dirty and so women used to bathe after immersing. As a result, people began to believe that both the *mikve* and bath were required for purification. The Rabbis therefore decreed that it is forbidden to bathe after immersing in
the mikveh (Shabbat 14a and Rama to Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh
Deah 201:75).

**Today, regarding women who want to bathe after the mikveh, it
is permissible to wash the body one part at a time:** the hands,
then the feet, then the head, then the back, etc.

R Aviner then brings an interesting chidush from R Yosef
Shalom Elyashiv that a
shower does not wash the entire body all at one time but part by
part. And even if the shower covers the entire body, each drop
of water is still separate and touches a different part of the body.
**This "chidush" allows a woman to shower after immersion in the
mikveh if she wishes, but she is certainly not obligated to do so.**

Answer (score 0):

> והבא ראשו ורובו במים שאובין מ"ט גזרו ביה רבנן טומאה א"ר ביבי אמר
>
> רב אסי שבתחלה היו טובלין במי מערות מכונסין וסרוחין והיו נותנין עליהן
> מים שאובין התחילו ועשאום קבע גזרו עליהם טומאה
>
> מאי קבע אמר אביי שהיו אומרים לא אלו מטהרין אלא אלו ואלו מטהרין אמר ליה
> רבא מאי נפקא מינה הא קא טבלי בהנך אלא אמר רבא שהיו אומרים לא אלו
> מטהרין אלא אלו מטהרין
>
> וטהור שנפלו על ראשו ורובו שלשה לוגין מים שאובין מ"ט גזרו ביה רבנן
> טומאה דאי לא הא לא קיימא הא

This has nothing to do with impurity of nidda. It is a Rabbinic tum'a that makes one sheni lattum'a.

A woman who is permitted to her husband does not lose that status because she becomes teme'a by any other means (except zibha).

Secondarily, it may require that the waters fell on the person from a keli, not a hose, stream or shower.

Basically no issue with a woman showering after miqwa.

Comment: Hi Nicole, welcome to Mi Yodeya!  Consider clarifying your answer, as I don't see the connection between what you wrote and the conclusion that there is no issue with showering after miqwa.

Comment: Welcome to MY. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Hope to see you around!

Comment: @ shalom @ waf I heard in the name of Rav Eliashiv that the question of a man showering after tevilas Ezra would be dependent on what you hold about using a shower in place of Tevilas Ezra. But in the converse way to which it was presented here.Those who hold that a shower can be used for tehara should not shower

Comment: Those who hold that a shower MAY be used for tehara should NOT shower after a mikva, because unless the shower is done in the correct manner for tahara, we have the same cheshash as a woman bathing after tevilah. That being that one might thing that the final shower caused the tahara. But those who hold that a shower CANNOT be used instead of a tevilas ezra even with the right shiur and way of despension of the water, WOULD ALLOW showering after a mikvah EVEN for a woman.

Answer (score 0):

Gershon Gold, [in his answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8415/15571), provided the source for the Ashkenazi stringency not to shower (bathe) after immersing in the mikveh (though original opinions predate the cited Rema). However, the summary quoted there does not reflect the final consensus for Ashkenaz prevalent custom.

[R. Waldenberg](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_Waldenberg) ([Tzitz Eliezer 11:64](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14510&st=&pgnum=172&hilite=)) permits Ashkenazim to shower after immersion in the mikveh.

Comment: Providing evidence that "the summary quoted there does not reflect the final consensus for Ashkenaz prevalent custom" would greatly improve this post.

Comment: Fair point, though R. Daily Halacha's omission of one of the most prominent (Ashkenaz) poskim of 20-21st. cen. should speak for itself.