# Taking a shower after mikveh for men - where is the Ari source that one shouldn't?

Tags: sources-mekorot, men-male, mikvah-ritual-bath, showering-bathing, arizal

[A previous question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8414/taking-a-shower-after-the-mikvah) discusses whether **men** should avoid showering after using the Mikveh. I have heard specifically that the Ari Z"l frowned upon this. Can anyone please quote the source, if one does exist?

Comment: user2817, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Is this a dupe?

Comment: @DoubleAA, a duplicate? Arguably, but I'm not sure. To clarify, user2817, we don't leave duplicate questions open for answers, as we want answers in one place. We close any duplicate and point people to the open question. The question is whether this question is a duplicate of the one you mentioned, since it's asking for one specific source for an answer to the question there.

Comment: Continued at http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9533841#9533841 et seq.

Answer (score 3):

The source is Pri Eitz Chayim Sha'ar Hashabbos Chapter 3. (Quoted in Kaf Hachayim Siman 260 Sa'if Katan 4.)

Comment: Hi Meir, many thanks for answering. I have looked up in Kaf Hachaim and it is not clear about not showering. In the Pri Etz Chayim in Chapter 4 there is a comment about the Ari Zl not drying off the water of the Mikveh after immersing prior to Shabbos as he wanted to absorb the water of Shabbos. Is that what you were referring to? If so does that apply the rest of the week or have I missed the source altogether? Many thanks

Comment: I understand it doesn't say about showering after Mikvah. However he does write at the very end of Sa'if Katan 4 "According to סודם של דברים one has to FIRST wash himself... and AFTERWARDS to Tovel". Accordingly this implies that washing oneself before Toveling removes the unwanted "elements" and Toveling brings the Kedusha unto the person.

Comment: Many thanks. I will have another look at the Kaf Hachayim.

Answer (score 0):

In tractate Gittin, I'll try to find exactly where, there is mention of a rabbinic decree that actually caused drawn water to bring on ritual impurity. Rashi explains the reason.

Mikvehs used to be in caves, where the water could get, for lack of a better word, yucky. The rabbis saw that people would regularly bathe after going and wanted to make it clear that the post-immersion bathing played no part in the purification process.

How that translates to halacha nowadays, I have no idea, but this gemarah came to mind when I saw this question.

Edit: Here's the source: http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=gitin&daf=16a

10 lines down, and in Rashi, who brings down shabbos 14a:

http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=pesachim&daf=3a&go=Go

14 lines down.

Comment: The reason is in Gemara Shabbos. Though we don't go to mikva for Tahara (or only Tamei people would go)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Why do "we" go then?

Comment: @DoubleAA either because of laws of Nidda (for women) or "Tosfos Kedusha" for men.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Niddah is tumah... And what's Tosfos Kedusha? I thought you went to remove Keri (at least miderabanan) because of the potential prohibitions involved in Takkanat Ezra? Why would someone not Tamei Keri go to the Mikva (aside from _lo plug_ type reasons)?

Comment: @DoubleAA Tumas Nidda is different from Issur Nidda. The Badei Hashulchan (the bottom of the Ktzos Hashulchan) said that it's not truly because of Takanas Ezra, as unmarried people go also. He said that's why one can go to Mikva on Shabbos since it's not Tikun Mana (he has a long piece where he argues on the Mishna Brura regarding going to Mikva on Shabbos)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I don't really know what the difference is but if they are different, then the Mikva removes the Tumah. That's what Mikvaot do. Once she is Tehorah she no longer has an Issur, but it's because the Tumah is gone. If a woman goes to the Mikva with intent to remove the Issur and to not become Tehorah then I strongly suspect it doesn't work at all.

Comment: As for Keri, I haven't seen that piece inside, but I don't see what marriage has to do with anything as unmarried men can acquire Tumat Keri too. (That's actually what Keri means: [chance nocturnal emission](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0523.htm#11).) Nor do I follow how a human going to the Mikva is a problem of Tikkun Manah as we allow women to go all the time because of נראה כמקרר and it is clear that the same heter applied to anyone who needed to eat Teruma or Kodshim 2000 years ago. Also, I have no idea what Kedusha gets added to you by going to the Mikva if you aren't Tamei.

Comment: @DoubleAA we (Ashkenazim) don't mekarer anymore.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin But we still use the Mikva.

Comment: @DoubleAA The Mishna Brura said that one shouldn't go on Shabbos.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Where does he say that? Women use Mikvaot all the time on Shabbat. IAE this is a side point, as you haven't demonstrated anything that a Mikva would do to a Jew besides change them from Tamei to Tahor. So whether or not you can use the Mikva on Shabbat, Jews nowadays go to the Mikva all the time for Tahara purposes. And you haven't even mentioned the people who go the Mikva nowadays to eat Challah in the Diaspora or visit the external portions of the Temple Mount, which are _certainly_ Tahara related and thus your initial statement is refuted again.