# Ba'al Keri and Learning

Tags: minhag, torah-study, sexuality, mikvah-ritual-bath, leniencies

Many are stringent: if they become a bal keri (have a nocturnal emission) for any reason they don't learn or pray before going to the mikveh ("tevilas ezra"). However, even according to those that are stringent in this (chassidim, etc.) is there any possibility of leniency in order to avoid missing out on a certain regular Torah study one does each night (that he wasn't able to study before having relations or that he simply wants to stay up and study afterwards and he can't get to the mikveh that night)?

I have heard the Yismach Moshe is lenient in such a case but I was never able to locate the leniency in that book. Perhaps someone here knows that citation or another. Obviously, if one would miss out on doing a mitzva at its right time, he would be lenient; I'm asking more in a general case when one merely wishes to learn at night and can't get to the mikveh.

Comment: I've edited your question, as I and others have edited your past posts, to make it legible to those who speak English only and to fix some of the English grammar and usage. But really you should do so yourself if you can.

Comment: @msh210 http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6212553#6212553

Comment: @msh210 Many from the _heimishe oilem_ are _poshut_ unable to _zogn afilu_ a _mashehu_ without their English turning _kule_ _Yeshivish_. :-)

Comment: this tekana by ezra was done away with do prevent bitul torah. therefore going to the mikvah before davening or learning isn't a chiyuv. that being said it is still a valuable custom to do so as there was a reason this tekana was made to begin with and if a person is unable to go to a mikvah there are alternatives. 1. dumping water on ones head from a large container 2. taking a shower 3. learning hilchos mikvah

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, "Many are makpid". In other words, this is not a requirement. As such, I think it would depend on the level of [Kabbalah](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1028) a person had when deciding this was going to be a part of his lifestyle. If it was a Neder, then one could possibly have the Neder annulled.  If it was a Neder with caveats in it (for example, he said, "whenever possible"), then one could possibly find a leniency within the exception that was built in when it was decided that this would be the person's Minhag.

If someone was just doing it "like everyone else", presumably that would include one's Rav or a mentor that inspired him, and then I think that person would need to consult his Rav to determine exactly what "everyone else" does in that situation.

Comment: That's why it's hard to get a clear answer if one can be "makil" since the whole thing is only a "chumrah" and really only makes a difference perhaps in regards to nederim.

Comment: I think that's your answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any opinion that "Tevilas Ezra" was *not* botul for learning Torah (unlike Tefillah) (see [here](http://www.briskodesh.org/pages/bris/litah-mikva.htm) for some sources), as it is an explicit Gemara, specifically to avoid a situation of bitul Torah.

Of course if there is a Neder involved, that is a different story. And a [shower](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2966/mikvah-in-shower) should almost always be an option (unless the Neder really encompassed not using a shower as a heter, as the Neder could always be more strict that Tevilas Ezra).

So CLOR of course for practical guidance.