# Takanas Ezra and the 9 Kabin

Tags: blessing, talmud-gemara, torah-study, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, talmud-bavli

I would like to begin my question by making everyone aware that I am aware of this thread ( [Why don't men go to the mikveh after relations/ejaculation?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69956/20586) )

With that being said my question is would standing under 3.5 gallons of rainwater suffice for the "emergency" 9 Kabin in order to become tahor?

Comment: Possibly related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2966/mikvah-in-shower

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: I found evidence to support answering my question in the affirmative. In Tractate Shabbos Schottenstein Daf Yomi Edition page 5a<sup>2<sup> commentary #23 states that Merely allowing the water to collect in his hand is comparable to the poor man allowing the householder to place an object in his hand. Since the act of lifting was performed by another [person or by Heaven,] he cannot be held liable. Since the rainwater would be from Heaven it should suffice for the 9 Kabin. In my opinion.